# spring data jpa Pageable Sort Error

Tags: sorting, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot (1.3.5), spring-data, spring-data-jpa, JPA(hibernate/hsqldb).

The code:

POM:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
```

The code for configuration:

```
@Bean
public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(
        SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver) {

    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver phmar = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(
            sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver);
    phmar.setOneIndexedParameters(false);
    phmar.setPageParameterName("page");
    phmar.setSizeParameterName("size");
    phmar.setMaxPageSize(20);
    return phmar;
}

@Bean
public SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver sortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {

    SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver shmar = new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    shmar.setSortParameter("sort");
    return shmar;
}
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/List", "" })
public String list(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String searchString,
        @SortDefault(sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC) @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable) {
```

I try

```
@PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20, sort = "code", direction = Direction.ASC)
```

too, but it does not work.

```
Page<T> page;
if (!isEmpty(searchString))
   page = service.search(searchString, pageable); // <-- ERROR
else
   page = service.findAll(pageable);  // <-- OK
```

The service (simplified):

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<T> search(String str, Pageable pageable) {
    return repository.search(str, pageable);
}
```

The repository (simplified):

```
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
(...)
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%'))")
Page<T> search(@Param("str") String str, Pageable pageable);
```

I try whith the same `@Query` but return `List<>` intead `Page<>` without `Pageable pageable` parameter, and it works with this `@Query`

test:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM #{#entityName} a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%'))")
List<T> search(@Param("str") String str);
```

When I call `findAll(pageable)` it works but when I call `search(str, pageable)` (str="AT") it does not work.

Browser output:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed May 25 15:16:24 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 151 [SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 151 [SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]
```

**The SQL is invalid!  Extra ":" and duplicate "ASC asc".**

Console output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(accounttyp0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        account_type accounttyp0_ 
    where
        accounttyp0_.code like ('%'||?||'%') 
        or upper(accounttyp0_.name) like upper(('%'||?||'%'))
mo.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter       line 1:151: unexpected token:     :
mo.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter       line 1:151: unexpected token:     :

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: :
    at         org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3694)     [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]

(more and more)

near line 1, column 151 [SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a     WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE     UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]; nested exception     is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: :     near line 1, column 151 [SELECT a FROM prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE     a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR UPPER(a.name) LIKE     UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]] with root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:     : near line 1, column 151 [SELECT a FROM     prueba.entity.AccountType a WHERE a.code LIKE CONCAT('%', :str, '%') OR     UPPER(a.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :str, '%')) order by a.code: ASC asc]
    at     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxExcept    ion.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

Comment: Please structure and format your question, currently it is unreadable due to missing code blocks, half code blocks and formatting issues.

Comment: Sorry. Better now?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that during query generation u got that exception.For Pagination use spring-data-jpa you have to implement **PagingAndSortingRepository** Interface.

You have to write a method which takes parameters as **Pageable page** as and you can pass new **PageRequest(0,size)** as argument to Pageable and size is the no of records you want to fetch.

> Don't use @Query instead you can write method which is easy and you
>   can use all the supported key words in spring-data-jpa.you can check
>   below for supported keywords.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: My repository extends JpaRepository, and it works if use findAll(pageable), it is not the problem.

Comment: the problem with keyworks is that I don't see how I build complex sql with '()' like this:  where (a = b or (b=c and d=e) and (f=g or h!=j or i=null)).

Comment: The question is why it works with findAll(pageable) and @Query doesn`t build a valid sql with the same pageable (set by @PageableDefault)?

Comment: @MiguelAngel i don't understand why still you want to write complex sql queries if they provide easier way for you like findall() that will generate sql  queries on behalf of you

Comment: Because I need this complex SQL. findAll return all rows and I need build complex sql in my app. How do you build a complex sql only with keywords?

Comment: Do you have any idea?